# Using NSIS, How can I get the Key Value from a text file in Json format or a Json file?

Tags: json, nsis

I'm jin.
Thanks for reading my article :)

I am using NSIS, and I want to get the key value inside by using C++ dll to get a Json type string and save it as a text file or Json file. But even using nsJson I don't get the value. We will send you a simple example and code. thank you.

file Example : "ex.json" or "ex.txt"

```
[{"areaCode":"INF0411","areaName":"NewY","gradeCode":"INF0102"},
{"areaCode":"INF0412","areaName":"NewA","gradeCode":"INF0103"},
{"areaCode":"INF0413","areaName":"NewB","gradeCode":"INF0104"},
{"areaCode":"INF0414","areaName":"NewC","gradeCode":"INF0105"}]
```

In this situation, I want to get the key value of
every "gradeCode".

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use /index to access array nodes:

```
!macro prepare_example
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\data.json" w
FileWrite $0 '[{"areaCode":"INF0411","areaName":"NewY","gradeCode":"INF0102"},$\n'
FileWrite $0 '{"areaCode":"INF0412","areaName":"NewA","gradeCode":"INF0103"},$\n'
FileWrite $0 '{"areaCode":"INF0413","areaName":"NewB","gradeCode":"INF0104"},$\n'
FileWrite $0 '{"areaCode":"INF0414","areaName":"NewC","gradeCode":"INF0105"}]$\n'
FileClose $0
!macroend

!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
!insertmacro prepare_example

ClearErrors
nsJSON::Set /file "$PluginsDir\data.json"
nsJSON::Get /count /end
Pop $1
${For} $2 0 $1
    nsJSON::Get /index $2 "gradeCode" /end
    ${IfNot} ${Errors}
        Pop $0
        DetailPrint "Grade=$0"
    ${EndIf}
    ${Next}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: I've processed and commented. I'm really sorry, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to check the V mark next to the question!?